# How to set running sum in extra Gridview

Tags: c#, xtragrid

Hi i am using extra gridview from developer express i want to make sure that is it possible to set running sum on a column thanks

Comment: Yes it is. http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument699

Comment: dear in your link there will be total summary in footer cell i want the running summary in gridview cell not in footer cell